# implementation of multiple if else condition in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data frame is -

```
id       score
1          50
2          88
3          44
4          77
5          93
```

I want my data frame looks like -

```
id       score      is_good
1          50        low
2          88        high
3          44        low
4          77        medium
5          93        high
```

i have done the following code -

```
def selector(row):
    if row['score'] >= 0 and row['score'] <= 50 :
        return "low"
    elif row['score'] > 50 and row['score'] <=80 :
        return "medium"
    else:
        return "high"

x['is_good'] = x.apply(lambda row : selector(x), axis=1)
```

I think logic is fine but code is not working. May be we can use map function.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "code is not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in your code because of:

```
x['is_good'] = x.apply(lambda row : selector(x), axis=1)
```

should be :

```
x['is_good'] = x.apply(lambda row : selector(row), axis=1)
```

It was taking series not rows that's why you got the error.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good use case for [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['is_good'] = pd.cut(df.score, 
                       [-np.inf,50,80,np.inf], 
                       labels=['low','medium','high'])
```

---

```
print(df)
   id  score is_good
0   1     50     low
1   2     88    high
2   3     44     low
3   4     77  medium
4   5     93    high
```

Comment: df.score.max(). Would np.inf be faster?

Comment: I think I read somthing about that not being a great idea in pd.cut. Not sure 
 though @pinegulf

Comment: I think I do prefer it though :) @pinegulf

Comment: @yatu, what's the need for ``np.inf`` can you pls add some details ?

Comment: `np.inf` just contemplates the *edge*  bins. So from -inf to 50, that is low. And 80 to inf that is high @Sushanth

Comment: Just add the 'import numpy as np' for completion.

Comment: @yatu - getting error "ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional"

Comment: Is your column `score` duplicated..? @NikitaAgarwal

Answer (score 2):

You can use, [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) + [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)

```
import numpy as np

df['is_good'] = (
    np.where(df.score.between(0, 50), "low",
             np.where(df.score.between(51, 80), "medium", "high"))
)
```

---

```
   id  score is_good
0   1     50     low
1   2     88    high
2   3     44     low
3   4     77  medium
4   5     93    high
```

Comment: Sushanth - getting error "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'between'"